# How to get QgsFeatureId with row and column in qtablewidget.(PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis

In a QGIS python plugin. I like to change value selected cell in qtablewidget to the typed value. Something like screenshot below.

[image]

But in changeattributevalue function. While column(second value) and string(third value) is really easy to get. I really can't find a way to get "QgsFeatureId"(first value) with row and columns of qtablewidget.

If I do something like below. It will always change wrong row.

```
layer.changeAttributeValue(long(table.selectedIndexes()[0].row()), table.selectedIndexes()[0].column(), changestring.text())
```

I tried to use QgsFeatureRequest() with unique column field, but I really don't know how to use this function with variables and scanning whole table seems ununnecessary.

(ex: `request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression( u' header[table.selectedIndexes()[0].column()] = table_data[0][table.selectedIndexes()[0].row()]' )`)

Is there any way to get QgsFeatureId based on row number?

Comment: Feature ID is a row number in a "standard" QGIS table, so if you are sure your plugin does not do any sorting, you can just use it. I can't find any possibility how can you get fid if any of the data was sorted (during appending, calculating or whatever). After all, you just pasted a raw value into a table, so if they are unique, scanning every feature would be the only way.

Comment: I didn't do any sorting and I'm sure about it. But above long(row()) doesn't work and edits some rows away from clicked cell. could there be something missing that I couldn't find?

Comment: Well I think there is some kinda shaking things up while reading data from features. Gotta look into it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the feature ID when constructing `QTableWidgetItem` objects.

Qt gives you a handy method to store any data you need into a `QTableWidgetItem` (besides the displayed value).

```
item = QTableWidgetItem( someValue )
item.setData( Qt.UserRole, feature.id() )
self.mytable.setItem( row, column, item )
```

Once you have the selected item, you can retrieve such data in this way:

```
fid = item.data( Qt.UserRole )
```

Comment: Thanks! That surely solved the problem. It worked perfectly.